# BMI Calculator / Square root issue

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, calculator, square-root

I have an assignment in my first CSC class which is focused around Python 3. This is my second batch of code, so pardon if it's elementary.

The assignment is to create a BMI calculator. A BMI is found by a person’s weight in (pounds) times 720.0 , divided by the square of the person’s height (in inches).

The requirements are:
Prompt user to enter his/her weight in pounds.
Prompt user to enter part of height in feet. 
Prompt user to enter part of height in inches. 
Tell whether user is above or within or below the healthy range. (19-25)

Here is my code so far:

```
#problem1_<tomjenk>.py
#A program used to calculate range of BMI.
import math

def main():
    print("BMI Calculator")
    print()
    print("Please fill out the following:")
    x = eval(input("Your weight in pounds: "))
    y = eval(input("Your Height in feet: "))
    z = eval(input("Your remainder inches: "))
    q = y / 12.0
    f = x * 720.0
    t = q + z
    d = math.sqrt(t)
    total = f / d 
    print("Total", total)
main()
```

Comment: You could use more descriptive variable names... Or at least `p` for pounds, `f` for feet, etc. instead of completely arbitrary one-letter variables.

Comment: @kharybdis Nope, [not in Python3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#print).

Comment: *"A BMI is found by a person’s weight in (pounds) times 720.0"* It should be times 703, not 720; also why are you using `eval(input(...))`?

Comment: To get the number of inches in a foot, you multiply by 12, not divide.

Comment: Who teaches the use of `eval`? Avoid this teacher.

Comment: It's gonna be a long semester.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use square root.  It is height squared which is t*t.  And on a side note, you didn't really ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

```
  q = y / 12.0
```

1 inch = 12 feet? Shouldn't you multiply the feet by 12 to get inches?

```
   d = math.sqrt(t)
   total = f / d
```

This is not the formula you describe. You are supposed to square t, not take the square root.